# How to use contains on array of class

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

```
class product
{
 attribute
 setter method
 getter method
}

public class main...
{
 Array List of <Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
 boolean checkProduct = products.contains(....); // This is the problem how to use contains on this?
}
```

The method to check value in array of class, contains doesn't work for this.

Comment: An `ArrayList` in Java is not the same thing as an array.

Comment: Do you have to use `contains`?  You could perform the test using `boolean found = products.stream().anyMatch(p -> targetValue.equals(p.getAttribute()));`.

Answer (score 1):

`contains()` method uses `equals()` method to check if an object is in the list. If you haven't overridden the `equals()` method in your `Product` class, it will use the one from `Object`, which only returns true if the two objects are the same object in memory. You need to override the `equals()` method in your `Product` class to define what makes two `Product` objects equal.

example:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Product other = (Product) obj;
    if (attribute == null) {
        if (other.attribute != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!attribute.equals(other.attribute))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Once you implement `equals()` its recomended to also override the `hashCode()` method. If you don't do so, equal objects may get different hashes, and hash based collections (`HashMap`, `HashSet`, ..) will not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the equals method for your class product. In Eclipse you can do this by right clicking in editor, then Source > Generate hashCode() and equals().

Answer (score 0):

Override the *equals* and *hashCode* methods of *Product*, pointing them to the unique attribute.

Additionally, *sub-class* *ArrayList*, and *override* the *contains* method.

Here is an example.

```java
record Product(String s) {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return s.equals(((Product) obj).s);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return s.hashCode();
    }
}
List<Product> ps = new ArrayList<>() {
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        for (Product p : this)
            if (p.s.equals(o)) return true;
        return false;
    }
};
ps.add(new Product("abc"));
ps.add(new Product("123"));
System.out.println(ps.contains("xyz"));
System.out.println(ps.contains("123"));
```

Output

```
false
true
```

Comment: Why the override of `contains`?

Comment: Why does your Product record class override equals and hashCode?  The default implementations would do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

- Override `equals` (and `hashCode`) on your `Product` class.
  Tip: Let your IDE generate the code for these two methods.
- Call `List#contains`.

## Override `equals`

The [Answer by Reilas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77212004/642706) is good. Overriding [`Object#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is key here. But a couple notes:

- Subclassing `ArrayList` seems a bit extreme just to do a `contains`. Unnecessary after overriding `equals`.
- Alternate syntax is possible, using [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html) utility class.

I see no need to subclass [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html). The [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) interface defines a [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method, and `ArrayList` already contains a proper implementation.

Below is some similar example code. The `equals` & `hashCode` implementations were [generated by IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-equals-and-hashcode-wizard.html) [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

Important: When overriding either `equals` or `hashCode`, **always override both**, using consistent logic.

Define your class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) if its main purpose is to transparently communicate shallowly-immutable data. Note that a `record` can be defined locally, as seen here. (Ditto for `interface` and `enum` in Java 16+, by the way.)

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ExContains
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        ExContains app = new ExContains ( );
        app.demo ( );
    }

    public void demo ( )
    {
        record Product( UUID id ,
                        String name ,
                        BigDecimal price )
        {
            @Override
            public boolean equals ( Object o )
            {
                if ( this == o ) return true;
                if ( o == null || getClass ( ) != o.getClass ( ) ) return false;
                Product product = ( Product ) o;
                return Objects.equals ( id , product.id );
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode ( )
            {
                return Objects.hash ( id );
            }
        }

        List < Product > products =
                List.of (
                        new Product ( UUID.fromString ( "ca4cf3ce-8d41-487a-9429-dcc3540d96d1" ) , "one" , new BigDecimal ( "11.11" ) ) ,
                        new Product ( UUID.fromString ( "8f9f749b-c265-40f2-9411-c6980b35810f" ) , "two" , new BigDecimal ( "22.22" ) ) ,
                        new Product ( UUID.fromString ( "ad28633a-eea6-44c2-af92-4bfb8ca4b924" ) , "three" , new BigDecimal ( "33.33" ) )
                );
        Product a = new Product ( UUID.fromString ( "8f9f749b-c265-40f2-9411-c6980b35810f" ) , "a" , new BigDecimal ( "42.42" ) );  // Same UUID as second element in list, but different name & price.
        Product b = new Product ( UUID.randomUUID ( ) , "two" , new BigDecimal ( "22.22" ) );  // Different UUID, but same name and price as second element in list.
        System.out.println ( "contains a = " + products.contains ( a ) );
        System.out.println ( "contains b = " + products.contains ( b ) );

        System.out.println ( "products = " + products );
        System.out.println ( "a = " + a );
        System.out.println ( "b = " + b );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
contains a = true
contains b = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry at first that my english is lame so the question is unclear, But I found another way to use contains instead of everyone method here the sample.

```
public class Product 
{
    private String product_id;
    private String product_name;
    private Double product_price;
    private int product_stockamount;

    setter, getter method
}

public class main...
{
    ArrayList <Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    String getpid = Product id you want to find.
    int getamount = Amount of product people want to buy.
    int productStatus = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= products.size(); i++)
    {
        if(products.get(i).getproduct_id().equals(getpid) && products.get(i).getproduct_stockamount() >= getAmount)
        {
          products.get(i).setproduct_stockamount(getAmount);
          productStatus = 1;
        }
    }

    if(productStatus > 0)
    {
        Do anything you want to do...
        At finally 
        productStatus = 0;
    }
}
```